# Where's Qt Designer on Linux installation of PySide2 (Qt for Python)?

Tags: linux, qt-designer, pyside2

After installing with `pip install PySide2` it's at: `site-packages\PySide2\designer.exe` on Windows, but I don't see any counterpart on my Ubuntu installation.

[Pyside2 page on pypi.org](https://pypi.org/project/PySide2/) isn't very helpful as Qt for Python Team left `Project description` page empty.

Does it mean `Qt Designer` is just not bundled for some reason with the Linux distribution of `Qt for Python` and one has to look for some `PyQt` packages to remedy the situation? If that's the case, which ones?

Comment: Qt Designer is a separate package from PySide/PySide2 and PyQt4/PyQt5, it may be that in some cases the packages come with it but that is generally in Windows or Mac OS but in Linux it is usually provided by the OS, in the case of ubuntu execute: `sudo apt-get install qttools5-dev-tools` as [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/651461/where-is-qt5-designer) indicates (I have not tested it but in the post propose other solutions)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[eyllanesc's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53714304/wheres-qt-designer-on-linux-installation-of-pyside2-qt-for-python#comment94284584_53714304) is the answer.
`Qt Designer` **is not bundled** with the Linux distribution of `Qt for Python` that you get by means of `pip install PySide2`. Using `apt` remedies situation:

`sudo apt install qttools5-dev-tools`